# jquery each and ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, each

I would like to style a Download Page with jquery.

The user enters a Link to a file from the Backend and the JS on the frontend does the rest. Thet means it gets the filesize via ajax. So I have something like this:

```
$(".downloads a").each(function() {
  var link = $(this);
  request = $.ajax({
    type: "HEAD",
    url: link.attr("href"),
    success: function() {
      var length = request.getResponseHeader("Content-Length");
      if (!isNaN(parseInt(length))) {
        var fileSize = readablizeBytes(length);
        var type = link.attr("href").split('.').pop();
        var text = link.html();
        link.html(text+'<span class="info">'+type+' - '+ fileSize  +'</span>');
      }
    }
  });
});

function readablizeBytes(bytes) {
  var s = ['bytes', 'kb', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB'];
  var e = Math.floor(Math.log(bytes)/Math.log(1024));
  return (bytes/Math.pow(1024, Math.floor(e))).toFixed(2)+" "+s[e];
}
```

It works fine if I have only one Link. If I have two or more, only the last "a" get the "`<span class="info">`". Do you have an Idea how to fix this?

(All requests are executed, but the "link.html" functions only on the last "a")

Comment: The script should work: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qh67h/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What looks strange to me is that you use `request = $.ajax()` without `var` which means you override the next higher definition of `request`. If none is defined it will be in the global scope (`window.request`).

This could cause problems.

Rewrite it like:

```
$(".downloads a").each(function() {
  var link = $(this);
  $.ajax({
    type: "HEAD",
    url: link.attr("href"),
    success: function(data, textStatus, request) {
      var length = request.getResponseHeader("Content-Length");
      if (!isNaN(parseInt(length))) {
        var fileSize = readablizeBytes(length);
        var type = link.attr("href").split('.').pop();
        var text = link.html();
        link.html(text+'<span class="info">'+type+' - '+ fileSize  +'</span>');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Although I can't reproduce your problem in any way.

Comment: Great! That solved it! Thank you very much. I defindet it before the loop (var request;), but it seems I deleted it during the work.

Comment: @MarcelGwerder, Thank you for this! After 2 hours, and dozens of posts, this was the winner. Creating a reference outside of the AJAX call was what I needed. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
var link = $(obj);
```

To

```
var link = $(this);
```

And try that.

Comment: I changed it. But it didn't sovled the problem.